# CoffeeScriptの値の参照の参照のしかたを教えて下さい

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

```
obj =
  flag: true
  toggle_flag: ->
    flag = !flag

obj.flag        # true
obj.toggle_flag # false

obj.flag = true
obj.flag        # true
obj.toggle_flag # false
```

このような振る舞いのオブジェクトを作りたいのですが、
`toggle_flag`の中で`obj.flag`を参照するにはどうしたらよいのでしょうか。
`toggle_flag`の中で`this.flag`とするのかと思ったのですが、この場合`this`は`toggle_flag`をさすのか`obj`をさすのかわからず、困っています。

正しい知識を得たいので詳しく教えていただけないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コンパイル結果は以下のようになります。

```
var obj;
obj = {
  flag: true,
  toggle_flag: function() {
    var flag;
    return flag = !flag;
  }
};
//...
```

もし、`obj.toggle_flag()`で`obj.flag`を反転させ、その値を返したいのであれば

```
obj =
  flag: true
  toggle_flag: ->
    @flag = not @flag

obj.flag          # true
obj.toggle_flag() # false

obj.flag = true
obj.flag          # true
obj.toggle_flag() # false
```

としてください。

> [関数コンテキスト - > 和訳版 The Little Book on CoffeeScript - Syntax](http://minghai.github.io/library/coffeescript/02_syntax.html)

Comment: 回答有難うございます!!@をつけることで`obj.flag`を参照できるという解釈で正しいでしょうか。